# Match all the strings except www in URL rule apache 2

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

Here is my rule in URL manager of the application running with apache2 and mod_rewrite enabled:

```
'http://<username:\w+>.domain.com' => 'public/profile',
```

I want to rule to match in all the cases except when username is www. Means that when username is substituted with www then it should not pass. It should match in all the cases. I have done this but it's not working:

```
'http://<username:(?!www)([a-z0-9_-]+)\w+>.domain.com' => 'public/profile'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `'http://<username:(?!www\.)\w+>\.domain\.com' => 'public/profile',`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. But it did not work. The rule is not being matched. I want when abc.domain.com is hit then it should go to public/profile route and when www.domain.com or www.domain/* routes are hit then it should run relevant routes (controller actions). But with above rule abc.username.com is not hitting that route.

Comment: It's working now. It worked without backslash i.e http://<username:(?!www\.)\w+>.domain.com' => 'public/profile

You can add this as answer and I will accept. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to skip the rule when it starts with `www.`:

```
'http://<username:(?!www\.)\w+>.domain.com' => 'public/profile',
```

`(?!www\.)` is a negative lookahead to assert failure when we have `www.` at the start.